# Встреча соединительного союза и подчинительного союза

Tags: пунктуация

> Он носил тёмные очки, фуфайку, уши закладывал ватой, и когда садился на извозчика, то приказывал поднимать верх (Ч.)

– союз *и* соединяет однородные члены предложения;

но разве если союз *и* соединяет однородные члены (а какие здесь это однородные члены: закладывал и приказывал), то запятая ставится?

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, перед "и когда" запятая не нужна, так как "и" соединяет однородные члены "закладывал" и "приказывал"

Comment: в том-то и дело, что так пишет Розенталь. Не могу понять, почему нужна перед И запятая.

Comment: А откуда вы взяли фразу с запятой перед "и"? Не из тестов ли ЕГЭ? Там глупостей хватает, особенно в тренировочных вариантах.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая выделяет придаточное "когда садился на извозчика". Но здесь двойной союз "когда... то", поэтому поставить запятую перед "когда" мы не можем. При изъятии придаточного получится неправильная структура: Уши закладывал ватой и то приказывал поднимать верх.

Запятая стыка союзов И и КОГДА переносится и ставится перед И. Если ее не поставить, получится "уши закладывал ватой и когда садился на извозчика" - исказится смысл. Правила пунктуации рассматривают такие случаи как присоединение сложноподчиненного предложения (когда садился на извозчика, то приказывал поднимать верх).

Answer (score 1):

Синтаксическая роль союза И, соединяющего однородные члены, МЕНЯЕТСЯ, если  после И следует двойной подчинительный союз.  В этом случае перед  И ставится запятая (союз И соединяет уже не однородные члены, а присоединяет целое СПП):

А. Нет двойного союза

(1) "Он носил тёмные очки, фуфайку  и,  когда садился на извозчика,  приказывал поднимать верх".

Возможна ПЕРЕСТАНОВКА  придаточного: Он носил тёмные очки, фуфайку  и приказывал поднимать верх, когда садился на извозчика.  Союз И соединяет однородные сказуемые.

Б. Двойной союз

(2) "Он носил тёмные очки, фуфайку, и когда садился на извозчика, то приказывал поднимать верх".

Перестановка придаточного невозможна при наличии двойного подчинительного союза КОГДА…ТО, поэтому союз И соединяет простое предложение и СПП